# Fourier transformation of multidimensional list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fourier-analysis, map

`x` is a list containing 7 trajectories (`Dimensions[x] = {2726, 7}`) of which I want to calculate the FFT.

```
x = Get@"http://pastebin.com/raw/6tX4GBxA";
sr = 60; (*sampling rate*)
inc = sr/Length[x[[All, 1]]]; (*increment*)
freq = Table[f, {f, 0, sr - inc, inc}] // N;
```

FFT for first trajectory:

```
ampFFT = Abs[Fourier[x[[All, 1]], FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{freq, ampFFT}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, sr/2}, All}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"Amplitude (x)", ""}, {"f (Hz)", ""}},
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

plot 1:

[image]

Now I want to calculate the FFT for the whole list at once:

```
ampFFT = Abs[Fourier[x, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]];
```

From that the FFT for the first trajectory is:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{freq, ampFFT[[All, 1]]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, sr/2}, All}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"Amplitude (x)", ""}, {"f (Hz)", ""}},
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

plot 2:

[image]

**What surprises me, plot 2 is different from plot 1.** There must be a mistake.

**Where is my error?**

The same plot 2 is also obtained when I do the following:

```
ampFFT = Abs[Fourier[# & /@ x, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{freq, ampFFT[[All, 1]]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, sr/2}, All}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"Amplitude (x)", ""}, {"f (Hz)", ""}},
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

My final aim is to calculate the FFT for the whole list at once and plot all FFTs in a single plot:

If I would calculate ampFFT correctly I would do this the following way:

```
ampFFT = Abs[Fourier[# & /@ x, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{freq, #}] & /@ Transpose[ampFFT], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, sr/2}, All}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"Amplitude (x)", ""}, {"f (Hz)", ""}},
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

plot 3:

[image]

Comment: When you do `Fourier[x]` you're doing a 2D Fourier transform on the original grid. When you do `Fourier[x[[All,1]]]` you're doing a 1D Fourier on one column of the data. To do separate FFT's on each trajectory try `ampFFT = Abs[Fourier/@(Transpose@x)]`. You can also use the option data range so you don't need to explicitly give the freq. list. Try: `ListLinePlot[ Abs[Fourier/@(Transpose@x)], DataRange->{0,sr}, PlotRange->{{0, sr/2},All},ScalingFunctions->"Log"]`

Comment: Great ... please see only a small problem: http://imgur.com/d2PQv8c . Your FFT has an other vertical scaling, probably because I use `FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}`. How can this be added, since this should be used for data analysis? Please put it into an answer, so that I can accept it as solution.

Comment: You can do `ampFFT = Abs[Fourier[#,FourierParameters->{-1,1}]&/@(Transpose@x) ]`

Comment: Solved ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying Fourier to a multi-dimensional array does a multi-dimensional FFT, so your first case generates the 2D FFT of all the trajectories. In your case you want to map the 1D FFT over each trajectory.

`ampFFT = Abs[Fourier[#,FourierParameters->{-1,1}]&/@(Transpose@x);`

Now each element of `ampFFT` is the 1D FFT of one trajectory, i.e. `ampFFT[[i]] == Abs@Fourier[x[[All,i]], FourierParameters->{-1,1}]`

Another helpful option is `DataRange` which you can use to specify the x axis without providing an explicit list of x values when your data is evenly sampled. `PlotRange` can now be specified in the same units as `DataRange`

```
ListLinePlot[ ampFFT, 
 DataRange->{0,sr}, 
 PlotRange->{{0, sr/2},All},
 ScalingFunctions->"Log"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Please see this: http://imgur.com/tQ0HgMZ